# Serializing c# use switch to serialize a Readme

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, switch-statement, readme

I developed an application which offers regression testing functionality to other developers within my organization internally, and the main way that they interface through the front-end of application is via hard-copded strings that correspond to a switch case structure in the code like such:

```
           case "BUILDTEST":
                //Build the test with the supplied designator as 'arg_designator'
                returnVal = BuildDesignator();
                break;

            case "CHANGEROLE":
                //Changes the user's role
                returnVal = ChangeRole();
                break;

            case "CHECKOUTDATA":
                //Check out the data you wish to test
                returnVal = CheckoutRoute();
                break;
```

What is the best way to serialize the names and comments below the case to generate a some sort of readme file every build? In this example I would like to generate a file that looks like:

```
FUNCTIONALITY

BUILDTEST: Build the test with the supplied designator as 'arg_designator'

CHANGEROLE: Changes the user's role

CHECKOUTDATA: Check out the data you wish to test
```

Thank you for any assistance offered

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a bit of restructuring, here is a better solution than serializing the contents of the switch statement. I highly doubt you want to run regex find/replace operations over that source or mess around with adding files to help with deriving the switch contents.

First, make sure each of your build action classes inherits from a base class. While you do that, give each build action class a description to make things easier:

```
public abstract class BuildAction
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    protected BuildAction(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }

    public abstract void PerformBuildAction();
}

public class BuildTest : BuildAction
{
    public BuildTest() : base("Build the test with the supplied designator as 'arg_designator'") { }

    public override void PerformBuildAction() 
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

public class ChangeRole : BuildAction
{
    public ChangeRole() : base("Change the user's role") { }

    public override void PerformBuildAction()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

public class CheckoutData : BuildAction
{
    public CheckoutData : base("Check out the data you wish to test") { }

    public override void PerformBuildAction()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

After that you can get rid of your switch statement and replace it with a generic factory. Depending on how you make the factory, you can leverage it for your readme generation by first building a directory to iterate through for the readme and simplify the lookup for your command routing:

```
public class BuildActionFactory
{
    private static IDictionary<string, BuildAction> _buildActions =
        new Dictionary<string, BuildAction>()
        {
            {"BUILDTEST", typeof(BuildTest)},
            {"CHANGEROLE", typeof(ChangeRole)},
            {"CHECKOUTDATA", typeof(CheckoutData)}
        };

    public static BuildAction CreateBuildAction(string directive)
    {
        return _buildActions.ContainsKey(directive) ?
            Activator.CreateInstance(_buildActions[directive]) :
            null;
    }

    public static string BuildReadme()
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine,
            new [] {"FUNCTIONALITY"}.Union(_buildActions.Select(pair => pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value.Description));
    }
}
```

If you make your factory like that, your switch statement can be replaced by a simple call to `BuildActionFactory.CreateBuildAction("BUILDTEST/CHANGEROLE/CHECKOUTDATA/etc whatever you got from the user").PerformBuildAction()` and then your readme contents can be generated by `BuildActionFactory.BuildReadme()`. Of course, if you want the readme built when the solution builds, you would need to add a post build task that calls `BuildActionFactory.BuildReadme()` from a wrapper console app project but that's simpler than refactoring to read in a configuration file you can generate a readme from.

Disclaimer: all of the above code was written in Sublime. None of it has been compiled or tested but it should give you an idea of what to do if you take this approach.

Comment: My release got pushed back so I never got around to implementing this. I'll keep you posted in a couple months when push comes to shove. Thanks a million for such an in-depth suggestion